# sql triggers - want to compare existing row value with value being inserted

Tags: sql, triggers, insert

I am creating a trigger that should compare of the values being inserted with one that already exists in the table.  The old referencer doesn't work here because I am inserting, but how can I reference something that already exists?
Here is my tables and trigger:

```
    create table events(eid char(2) primary key, cid char(2));

    create table activities(mid char(2), eid char(2),
    primary key (mid, eid),
    constraint activities_fk foreign key (eid) references events(eid));

    create or replace trigger check_valid
    before insert or update on activities
    for each row when (old.mid=new.mid)
    declare
v_eid char(2);
v_cid char(2);
n_cid char(2);

    begin
select eid into v_eid from activities 
where mid=:new.mid;

select cid into v_cid from events
where eid=v_eid;

select cid into n_cid from events
where eid=:new.eid; 

if v_cid=n_cid then
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'Error');
end if;
    end check_valid;
    /
    show errors;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't generally select from the table you're inserting into in a trigger. This is the mutating table problem, or as I often call it, the "damn mutating table problem".

Basically, don't do this. It's a bad idea. What happens if you have two sessions operating on the table at once? The trigger fires and neither session sees what the other has done until the commit, which is after the trigger. Then you've got unexpected data in your database.

[Tom Kyte says](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:9579487119866), "when I hit a mutating table error, I've got a serious fatal flaw 
in my logic."